# Matplotlib plot bar chart with 2 columns relationship in dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pyspark

I have been stuck at plotting dataframe.
This might be simple, but I can't able to figure out!

I have panda dataframe records like this:

```
    Year  occurrence   Count
0   2011           0     306
1   2011           1    1838
2   2012           0     422
3   2012           1    1816
4   2013           0     423
5   2013           1    3471
6   2014           0     537
7   2014           1    3239
8   2015           0     993
9   2015           1    7668
10  2016           0     415
11  2016           1    2052
12  2017           0     511
13  2017           1    4750
14  2018           0     705
15  2018           1    2125
```

I want to plot this dataframe as bar chart such that, x-axis contains Year and Y-axis contains Count.

1. **Now I want to plot this Count based on occurrence value. means that in year 2011 one bar has count=306 and second bar has count=1838, same for remaining years.**
2. Also, if possible, **I also have to display stacked bar chart based on same thing.**
3. And, **How can I plot line charts with two lines in it?**

   Can anyone have workaround on this?

   I have created sample df based on my result:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame({
(2011,  0,   306),
(2011,  1,  1838),
(2012,  0,   422),
(2012,  1,  1816),
(2013,  0,   423),
(2013,  1,  3471),
(2014,  0,   537),
(2014,  1,  3239),
(2015,  0,   993),
(2015,  1,  7668),
(2016,  0,   415),
(2016,  1,  2052),
(2017,  0,   511),
(2017,  1,  4750),
(2018,  0,   705),
(2018,  1,  2125),
}, ['Year', 'occurrence', 'Count'])

pdf_1 = df.toPandas()
```

I have tried with this:

```
pdf_1.plot(x='Year', y=['Count'], kind='bar')
```

but it does not give me what exactly I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to reshape:

```
pdf_1.pivot('Year', 'occurrence', 'Count').plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, for quick answer! Also, do you know how can I simply plot line and bar(2 bars per year) chart with same condition?

Answer (score 1):

As per @BigBen,

I have figured out all three answers:

```
# For Question 1
pdf_1.pivot(index='Year', columns='above_threshold', values='Count').plot.bar()

# For Question 2
pdf_1.pivot('Year', 'above_threshold', 'Count').plot.bar(stacked=True)

# For Question 3
pdf_1.pivot(index='Year', columns='above_threshold', values='Count').plot.line()
```